# Convert string (with UTC) to DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DateTime.ParseExact format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675421/datetime-parseexact-format-string)

How do I convert a string to a DateTime object?

Example:

> Sun Oct 07 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

I have tried, DateTime.Parse, Convert.TODateTime, etc. None work. I get an error that it is not a valid DateTime string.

Here is how I am sending datetime to MVC controller's action method from jquery:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("actionMethodName", "controllerName")',
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        data: {
               startDate: start.toLocaleString(),
               endDate: end.toLocaleString()
         },
         success: function (data) {
         }
});
```

I need to be able to get the datetime back in the controller action method:

```
public JsonResult actionMethodName(string startDate, string endDate)
{
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(startDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(endDate))
        {
            var start = DateTime.Parse(startDate); //Get exception here
            var end = DateTime.Parse(endDate);     //Get exception here 
        }

        //Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Where are you stuck? How many other examples do you have?

Comment: DateTime.Parse/DateTime.TryParse

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic. Both don't work

Comment: DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

Comment: I assume you are getting this from JS? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675421/datetime-parseexact-format-string

Comment: I believe you need to grab certain section of the string. The `DateTime` object can convert string of certain format. Look at the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) for full details

Comment: you are absolutely right @aquinas. I'm calling an MVC controller action method via ajax

Comment: @HasanFahim what is the exact string youre trying to parse?

Comment: @RoyiNamir. The string shown is exactly what I am getting in startDate paramter of the action method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the [`.toJSON()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) method on your javascript `Date` instances in order to serialize them as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("actionMethodName", "controllerName")',
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    data: {
        startDate: start.toJSON(),
        endDate: end.toJSON()
    },
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Now you don't need to be parsing anything in your controller, you will be working with dates directly:

```
public ActionResult ActionMethodName(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Darin Dimitrov. I was really struggling with this for long.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `DateTime.ParseExact` method. In this example I parsed out the `(Pakistan Standard Time)` part of the string.

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Sun Oct 07 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0500", 
    "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Check [these MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for more examples.

Comment: Still getting this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."