# Convert String to DateTime in VB

Tags: vb.net, datetime

How to convert following String to DateTime in VB?
I got error when executing code as below:

```
Dim date As String = "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"
DateTime.Parse(date)
```

> System.FormatException: "String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime."

Comment: The date you have given seems pretty confusing..

Comment: i got it using <input type="date">

Comment: Have you checked this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675421/datetime-parseexact-format-string ? as suggested, can you directly pass the timestamp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string is *clearly* not a standard date and time format for *any* culture.

But since your string has UTC Offset, I would parse it to `DateTimeOffset` instead. And since it does not keep timezone name and it's abbreviations, you need to escape them as a string literal delimiter. You can use `ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)'` format for that.

C#

```
var date = "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)";
var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(date, 
              "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)'",
              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

VB.NET

```
Dim [date] = "Wed Mar 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"
Dim dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact([date], "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz '(Malay Peninsula Standard Time)'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{30.03.2016 00:00:00 +08:00}`. Now you can use it's [`.DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.datetime) ot [`.UtcDateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime) properties as you want.

[image]

Comment: Ups, `c#` tag removed. Since I'm not familiar with `vb.net` syntax, I converted this code to `vb.net` with http://converter.telerik.com/